# 2007 Ford Fusion torque spec for torque strut (dogbone)

Tags: vibration, bolts, torque-specification

Can somebody please tell me the torque spec for torque strut mount (dogbone) 15mm bolt for 2007 Ford Fusion 2.3L ?

Comment: Have you done a search for a workshop manual? They can sometimes be found online.